# MYSQL SELECT statement Where last Date If Trace = 12

Tags: php, mysql

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sporesfungi` (
  `IDSpore` varchar(4) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `Type` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IDSpore`),
  KEY `IDSpore` (`IDSpore`)
)

 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sporecount` (
  `IDSpore` varchar(4) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `TraceNum` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `TraceHour` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `Amount` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Date` date NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `IDSpore_2` (`IDSpore`,`TraceHour`,`Date`),
  KEY `IDSpore` (`IDSpore`)
)
```

Since I can't still post images I put that, what I'm trying to do is take the `Type` from `sporesfungi` and `Amount` & `IDSpore` from `sporecount` and make an inner join, but from `sporecount` I only want the latest date data where It has `TraceNum` = 12 which is the highest value it will have.

So I want the all the data on the most recent date where the `TraceNum` reached 12.

This is what I have tried but no results yet

```sql
SELECT Amount, IDSpore, sporesfungi.Type FROM sporecount
    INNER JOIN sporesfungi ON sporecount.IDSpore = sporesfungi.IDSpore AS a
    WHERE Date = (
        SELECT MAX(Date)
            FROM sporecount AS b
            WHERE a.IDSpore = b.IDSpore)
    IF(MAX(b.TraceNum) = 12, 1, 0) =1
```

This is what I currently have on my table for testing.

```
    INSERT INTO `sporecount` (`IDSpore`, `TraceNum`, `TraceHour`, `Amount`, `Date`) VALUES
('C', 10, 1400, 1, '2015-05-14'),
('e', 4, 200, 1, '2015-05-14'),
('d', 8, 1800, 1, '2015-05-14'),
('r', 5, 0, 1, '2015-05-14'),
('t', 6, 2200, 1, '2015-05-14'),
('q', 2, 600, 1, '2015-05-14'),
('w', 3, 400, 1, '2015-05-14'),
('a', 1, 800, 1, '2015-05-14'),
('2', 12, 1000, 1, '2015-05-14'),
('y', 7, 2000, 1, '2015-05-14'),
('1', 9, 1600, 1, '2015-05-14'),
('A', 11, 1200, 1, '2015-05-14'),
('x', 9, 1630, 1, '2015-05-11'),
('z', 9, 1630, 1, '2015-05-11'),
('s', 9, 1630, 1, '2015-05-11'),
('s', 11, 1230, 1, '2015-05-11'),
('s', 1, 830, 2, '2015-05-11'),
('s', 2, 630, 1, '2015-05-11'),
('r', 10, 1430, 1, '2015-05-11'),
('d', 9, 1630, 1, '2015-05-11'),
('q', 6, 2230, 1, '2015-05-11'),
('q', 10, 1430, 2, '2015-05-11'),
('s', 8, 1830, 1, '2015-05-11'),
('t', 10, 1430, 1, '2015-05-11'),
('x', 11, 1230, 1, '2015-05-11'),
('x', 12, 1030, 2, '2015-05-11'),
('w', 6, 2230, 1, '2015-05-11'),
('w', 10, 1430, 1, '2015-05-11'),
('w', 11, 1230, 2, '2015-05-11'),
('x', 6, 2230, 2, '2015-05-11'),
('w', 2, 630, 1, '2015-05-11'),
('w', 5, 30, 1, '2015-05-11'),
('u', 7, 2030, 1, '2015-05-11'),
('y', 7, 2030, 1, '2015-05-11'),
('t', 7, 2030, 2, '2015-05-11'),
('v', 12, 1030, 2, '2015-05-11'),
('q', 5, 30, 2, '2015-05-11'),
('h', 7, 2030, 1, '2015-05-11'),
('a', 11, 1230, 1, '2015-05-11'),
('a', 12, 1030, 1, '2015-05-11'),
('a', 1, 830, 1, '2015-05-11'),
('a', 2, 630, 2, '2015-05-11'),
('T', 3, 430, 1, '2015-05-11'),
('S', 3, 430, 1, '2015-05-11'),
('R', 3, 430, 1, '2015-05-11'),
('D', 3, 430, 1, '2015-05-11'),
('1', 4, 230, 1, '2015-05-11'),
('C', 3, 430, 1, '2015-05-11'),
('4', 4, 230, 1, '2015-05-11'),
('3', 4, 230, 2, '2015-05-11'),
('a', 10, 1430, 1, '2015-05-11'),
('a', 8, 1830, 1, '2015-05-11'),
('h', 1, 830, 1, '2015-05-11'),
('g', 1, 830, 2, '2015-05-11'),
('e', 9, 1630, 1, '2015-05-11'),
('e', 10, 1430, 1, '2015-05-11'),
('e', 2, 630, 1, '2015-05-11'),
('e', 5, 30, 1, '2015-05-11'),
('d', 6, 2230, 1, '2015-05-11'),
('d', 8, 1830, 1, '2015-05-11'),
('d', 2, 630, 1, '2015-05-11'),
('c', 8, 1830, 1, '2015-05-11'),
('c', 12, 1030, 1, '2015-05-11'),
('a', 6, 2230, 1, '2015-05-11'),
('2', 4, 230, 1, '2015-05-11');

INSERT INTO `sporesfungi` (`IDSpore`, `Name`, `Type`) VALUES
('', '', ''),
('0', 'Basidiosporas', 'Fungus'),
('1', 'Ascosporas', 'Fungus'),
('2', 'Penicillum/Aspergillus', 'Fungus'),
('3', 'BasidiosporasPleurotus', 'Fungus'),
('4', 'Other', 'Fungus'),
('5', 'Cladospori', 'Fungus'),
('6', 'Coprinus/A', 'Fungus'),
('7', 'Basidio Tr', 'Fungus'),
('8', 'Ganoderma', 'Fungus'),
('9', 'Cecropia', 'Fungus'),
('A', 'Delitschia', 'Fungus'),
('C', 'Rumex', 'Trees'),
('D', 'Smut/Myxomycete', 'Fungus'),
('E', 'Spegazzinia', 'Fungus'),
('F', 'Sporomiella (A)', 'Fungus'),
('G', 'Torula', 'Fungus'),
('H', 'Pollen', 'Grass'),
('I', 'Arthrinium', 'Fungus'),
('J', 'Arbol', 'Trees'),
('K', 'Arthrocarpus', 'Trees'),
('L', 'Casuarina/Myrica', 'Trees'),
('O', 'Xylariae', 'Fungus'),
('P', 'Botrytis', 'Fungus'),
('Q', 'Spondylocladiella', 'Fungus'),
('R', 'Tetraploa', 'Fungus'),
('S', 'Diatrypaceae', 'Fungus'),
('T', 'Ulocladium', 'Fungus'),
('U', 'Amphisphaeria (A)', 'Fungus'),
('W', 'Stemphylium', 'Fungus'),
('X', 'Mimosa', 'Trees'),
('Y', 'Agrocybe-type', 'Fungus'),
('Z', 'Mangle', 'Trees'),
('a', 'Fusarium', 'Fungus'),
('b', 'Pleospora', 'Fungus'),
('c', 'Leptosphaerulina', 'Fungus'),
('d', 'Helocomyces', 'Fungus'),
('e', 'Periconia', 'Fungus'),
('f', 'Acrodictys', 'Fungus'),
('g', 'Alternaria', 'Fungus'),
('h', 'Bipolaris', 'Fungus'),
('i', 'Poaceae', 'Grass'),
('j', 'Cerebella', 'Fungus'),
('k', 'Dreshlera/Helmitosporum', 'Fungus'),
('l', 'Epicoccum', 'Fungus'),
('m', 'Rusts Puccinia', 'Fungus'),
('n', 'Nigrospora', 'Fungus'),
('o', 'Hifas Fragmentos', 'Fungus'),
('p', 'Curvularia', 'Fungus'),
('q', 'Ustilago', 'Fungus'),
('r', 'Helicoma', 'Fungus'),
('s', 'Helicomina', 'Fungus'),
('t', 'Leptosphaeria-Like', 'Fungus'),
('u', 'Chaetomiun', 'Fungus'),
('v', 'Pithomyces', 'Fungus'),
('w', 'Cercospora', 'Fungus'),
('x', 'Exserohilum', 'Fungus'),
('y', 'Tetrapyrgos', 'Fungus'),
('z', 'Erysiphe/Oidium', 'Fungus');
```

I hope I'm clear enough, any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You can't post embedded images, but you can upload to imgur and include a link in the post.

Comment: what do you want if there is no sporecount with tracenum = 12? no rows at all, or the sporesfungi data, with no corresponding values from the other table? can tracenum reach 12 more than once on a given day? in different hours?

Comment: @pala_ no, if there is no data with traceNum = 12 then I would like to check on the previous day if there is any. It will reach 12 only once per day.

Comment: is it guaranteed to reach 12 every day? what if its half way through the first day and 12 hasn't been reached?

Comment: well thats the point of this query, I don't want to display data that isn't complete (Trace = 12).

Comment: no problem. just verifying required output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a two step process to building this query. First, we need one that finds the last date where a spore reached a `tracenum` of 12. Since you say it can only reach 12 once per day, we ignore `tracehour`.

```
select idspore, max(`date`)
  from sporecount
  where tracenum = 12
  group by idspore
```

Then we need to join to the results of that query, to get the data from the sporesfungi table.

```
select sf.*, sc.amount
  from sporesfungi sf
    inner join sporecount sc
      on sf.idspore = sc.idspore
    inner join (
      select idspore, max(`date`) d
        from sporecount
        where tracenum = 12
        group by idspore
    ) q
    on sc.date = q.d
      and sc.idspore = q.idspore
  where sc.tracenum = 12  ;           -- we do this check again because the
```

subquery join will result in more than one row.

[demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63c0f/1)

**after updates**

From the comments - it seems we were on a different wavelength.  What you seem to want is find the last date where ANY spore hit a tracenum of 12, and then return ALL data, for ALL spores, on that day.  This actually simplifies things.

```
select sf.*, sc.*
  from sporesfungi sf
    inner join sporecount sc
      on sf.idspore = sc.idspore
    inner join (
      select max(`date`) d
        from sporecount
        where tracenum = 12
    ) q
    on sc.date = q.d;
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63c0f/15)

Comment: Ok, I'll try this and come back with the result I get.

Comment: @alf thanks for the data in the question - i've updated this answer with a demo. how do the results look?

Comment: well is supossed to give me at least 12 rows back, theres only 5

Comment: @alf why would you get 12? your sample data only has 5 rows with tracenum = 12

Comment: sorry If i wasn't clear enough, but i want to get all the rows on the last date which it reached 12, son on 14 that is today i want all of them from trace 1-12.

Comment: @alf getting rid of the where clause will probably do that. lets see... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63c0f/11 hows that look?

Comment: that's not quite it, it gave out data from both dates available, I'm trying too in the fiddle

Comment: @alf where? it gives out the data for each idspore on the day that idspore hit a tracenum of 12. ie, each idspore only has data from one day, but different idspores can have data from different days. Or do you want the data for all spores on the most recent day that ANY spore hit a tracenum of 12?

Comment: Yeah that's what I want

Comment: oh.  that simplifies things. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63c0f/15 -- updated in answer also.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
SELECT sc.Amount, sc.IDSpore, sf.Type
FROM sporecount sc INNER JOIN
  (SELECT IDSpore, MAX(Date) AS last_date 
    FROM sporecount 
   WHERE TraceNum= 12
   GROUP BY IDSpore
  ) last_sc
ON last_sc.IDSpore=sc.IDSpore 
  AND last_sc.last_date = sc.Date
INNER JOIN sporefungi sf
ON sf.IDSpore = sc.IDSpore
```

Comment: Ok, fixed it, but I'm not getting the data right, maybe is the GROUP BY?

Comment: Better show us some data and results. I am guessing there is something not clear about the tracehour.

Comment: Ill try to add some images of the current data in my table and results

Comment: textual representation would be better. easier to run tests against.

Comment: what about data for the other table?

Comment: :| how does that map to the fields of the table? :P

Comment: I made small changes since tracehour seems irrelevant. But you may still have do some more.

Comment: ok, now there is the other table, but from that I only need the type.

Comment: your small changes have turned your query into mine!

Comment: No problem. I'm kicking myself out. Please continue.